# Search value in all the properties and the nested properties in c# List

Tags: c#, .net, linq, search, ef-core-3.1

I have a object with the following properties where

```
class A{
  string name1 { get; set; }
  string name2 { get; set; }
  List<B> b { get; set; }
}

class B{
  string name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to find whether the following values available in the

```
List<A> a = new List<A>();
```

The values will be in a array
for example

```
string [] values = new string[]
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, what values ?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it in this way, [demo on fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Knysxi)

- Use [Contains](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=netframework-4.8) to where property
- Use [Intersect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.8) to where nested properties in c# List

```
    List<A> a = new List<A>
            {
               new A { name1 = "1", name2 = "2" },
               new A { name1 = "3", name2 = "4" },
               new A { name1 = "5", name2 = "6", b = new List<B> { new B { name = "7"}} },
               new A { name1 = "8", name2 = "9", b = new List<B> { new B { name = "10"}} },
            };
            string [] values = new [] { "1", "4", "7" }; 
            var result = a.Where(p => values.Contains(p.name1) 
                                        || values.Contains(p.name2) 
                                        || p.b.Select(p2 => p2.name).Intersect(values).Count() > 0);
            foreach(var item in result)
                Console.WriteLine(item.name1);
```

**Output**

```
1
3
5
```

Comment: Does this aswer your question? let me know if you need any help @Jeeva Jsb

Comment: You can do `p.b.Any(p2 => values.Contains(p2.name))` instead of the intersect and count.